# Cryptocurrency perpetual futures shorting mechanism

Tags: asset-pricing, cryptocurrency, bitcoin, contracts

I am trying to understand shorts in a perpetual futures market. Let's consider a market of ETH/USDC, trading at 1000 USDC. When user A shorts 1  perp (assuming no leverage) they pay 1000 USDC, the price of one  contract. Who receives this 1000 USDC? Since user B on the other side of  the contract, who is long, has also paid 1000 USDC for their position.  If user A places a long position for 0.5 perp, they will receive 500  USDC back, rather than paying another 500 USDC. How is this determined?

Comment: This question is most likely better suited for [Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This was already [posted](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/71836/54838) on Quant SE: cross-posting  is generally [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/989943).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was [cross-posted](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/71836/cryptocurrency-perpetual-futures-shorting-mechanism) to [Quant.SE].